# Testing a destroy action on a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

Is there a way to test a destroy action method where a record should not be deleted if utilized by another module (if it is a forign key to another table).

I am using rails mini test.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might need use transaction block in your testing section.

```
 User.transaction do
    User.destroy!
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to delete the record active record will throws an exception because it cannot delete the data.
So your test should be:

```
// add a record with a foreign key

begin
   post :destroy
   fail
rescue Exception => e
   // assert the exception type
end
```

So if the action throw the exception the test succeed otherwise fail.